# OpenVPN server not pushing route

Tags: routes, openvpn

I've a OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu server running, which is providing around 120 routes.

There's an issue with one of the routes not being pushed to the clients.

In the server.conf file the route is added as follows:

```
push "route xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.255"
```

The route works if it is added manually on the client device:

```
route add xx.xx.xx.xx/32 gateway
```

From the client side logs, the route does not appear at all in the list of server pushed routes and neither do any errors show up during the route push on the server side with the verbosity set to 9.

There are no conflicting routings, since each route is with an unique IP and the netmask of 255.255.255.255.

Comment: can you run `route print` on the client and search for any relevant info there?

Comment: Yes, theres nothing relevant sadly, the route doesnt get pushed at all during the connection and it's also missing from the routing table (due to it not being pushed).

Also for additional details: Tested this with 3 different client profiles, on Windows 10, Windows 11, Ubuntu 20.04 and Mac Catalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was from a configuration issue.

Ansible deployed the new configuration but the openvpn service kept on using an older configuration, even through service restarts.

The fix was to reboot the whole server causing openvpn to load the correct configuration.